# Help me to identify this pin

Tags: pins

I found this type of pin in some 3 pin female connector. I want to buy it but I don't know what is name of this pin :)
Any idea?

(I put dimensions approximatively)

[image]

Here are dimensions of plastic connector:

[image]

Comment: What is the connector it belongs to?

Comment: http://archive.benchmarkreviews.com/images/reviews/power/Antec%20TP3-650/3pinfansensor.jpg ...

Comment: Please post: a picture of an assembler connector, distance between the pins in the connector (pitch).

Comment: @Nick Alexeev, I edited post, please refresh

Comment: The picture of the 'plastic connector' does **not** match that of the connector shown in the link in your previous comment. They are two entirely separate examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely part of Molex's [KK Series](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=kk_254_rpc_connector_system&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors).

There are many alternatives made by other brands, and cheap generics, but that connector has perhaps been 'made famous' by its use as the default fan header in the ATX specification.

Comment: ?? ATX fans dont have 2mm square pins!  Oh that's the funnel that guides the pin!